# Undefined index en php y SQLite3

Tags: php, sqlite3

Necesito ayuda con un error, estoy insertando datos en una tabla llamada "posts" pero me da la noticia de que en ciertos campos en los que se permite null pone "Undefined index ... in ..........."

no entiendo porque se produce este error si supuestamente esos campos aceptan NULL.

Muchas gracias

Esto muestra en la pagina web que estoy haciendo como ejercicio

```
Aqui van los post
Notice: Undefined index: imagen in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: anio in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: mes in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: dia in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: subtitulo in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: texto in C:\xampp\htdocs\CursoVideo2Brain\blogphp\includes\posts.php on line 15
```

Aca esta el codigo que me genera el error:

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3('database/blogs.db');

$resultado = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE usuario='".$_SESSION['usuariotemporal']."' ORDER BY utc DESC LIMIT 3");

while($fila = $resultado->fetchArray())
{
    echo "
    <article>
    <div id='logov2b' style='background:url(\"photo/".$_SESSION['imagen'].".jpg\");'></div>
    <time>".$_SESSION['anio']."-".$_SESSION['mes']."-".$_SESSION['dia']."</time>
    <h3>".$_SESSION['titulo']."</h3>
    <h4>".$_SESSION['subtitulo']."</h4>
    <p>".$_SESSION['texto']."</p>
    <br/>";
    if($_SESSION['login'] == "yes")
    {
        echo "<a href='includes/eliminarpost.php?utc=".$fila['utc']."'>Eliminar</a><br/>";
    }

    if($_SESSION['login'] == "yes")
    {
        echo "<a href='index.php?titulomod=".$fila['titulo']."&subtitulomod=".$fila['subtitulo']."&textomod=".$fila['texto']."&editando=yes&utc=".$fila['utc']."'>Modificar</a><br/>";
    }

    echo "</article>";
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Comment: Ideal que pudieras agregar el código donde se te produce el error para intentar replicarlo.

Comment: Ok, ahora lo agrego

Comment: Corregi lo que me dijiste Eduardo Munizaga, pase la respuesta para arriba jaja =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que observo es que no estás insertando nada en la base de datos, estas generando una consulta `Select` por lo que estás obteniendo datos de la base de datos para desplegarlos. Los errores no tienen que ver con la consulta tienen que ver con las variables no definidas `imagen` , `anio` , `mes` , etc. La recomendación es que declares esas variables o utilices  `isset()` Ejemplo:

```
 `$variable= isset($_POST['variable']) ? $_POST['variable'] : '';`
```

o

```
if (isset($_POST['variable']) ){ 

        $variable=  $_POST['variable'];
}
```

0 en este caso

```
if (isset($_SESSION['variable']) ){ 

        $variable=  $_SESSION['variable'];
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Ya lo solucione, era que estaba poniendo variables de sesion cuando en realidad tenia que sacarlas del resultado de la consulta a la base de datos, pero muchas gracias por las rapidas respuestas, siempre viene bien un ojo de mas =D

Answer (score 1):

El error te da la respuesta. Estás tratando de imprimir variables de sesión que no están definidas. Deberías cambiar algo como:

```
$_SESSION['anio']
```

por

```
$fila['anio']
```

Creo que ahí está tu problema.